# Swift Playgrounds error

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

Ive been getting the following error a lot, whether I'm in a swift play ground, or Xcode project: ": calling -display has no effect." Is anyone else getting this issue? Has anyone been able to correct it? Im using version 7.3.1. Im trying to create shapes on screen to practice physics usage. Heres my code:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 480, height:320))
let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 480, height: 320))
sceneView.showsFPS = true
sceneView.presentScene(scene)
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = sceneView

let square = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "square")
square.name = "shape"
square.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width * 0.25, y: scene.size.height * 0.50)

let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
circle.name = "shape"
circle.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width * 0.50, y: scene.size.height * 0.50)

let triangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "triangle")
triangle.name = "shape"
triangle.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width * 0.75, y: scene.size.height * 0.50)

scene.addChild(square)
scene.addChild(circle)
scene.addChild(triangle)
```